# Converting from UIImage into cv::Mat, then back to UIImage is reducing image quality

Tags: c++, ios, objective-c, opencv, uiimage

I am using OpenCV for iOS and using the following two functions to convert UIImage into cv::Mat and vice versa

UIImage to cv::Mat:

```
+ (cv::Mat)toCVMat:(UIImage*)image
{
    // (1) Get image dimensions
    CGFloat cols = image.size.width;
    CGFloat rows = image.size.height;

    // (2) Create OpenCV image container, 8 bits per component, 4 channels
    cv::Mat cvMat(rows, cols, CV_8UC4);

    // (3) Create CG context and draw the image
    CGContextRef contextRef = CGBitmapContextCreate(cvMat.data,
                                                    cols,
                                                    rows,
                                                    8,
                                                    cvMat.step[0],
                                                    CGImageGetColorSpace(image.CGImage),
                                                    kCGImageAlphaNoneSkipLast |
                                                    kCGBitmapByteOrderDefault);

    CGContextDrawImage(contextRef, CGRectMake(0, 0, cols, rows), image.CGImage);
    CGContextRelease(contextRef);

    // (4) Return OpenCV image container reference
    return cvMat;
}
```

cv::Mat to UIImage:

```
+ (UIImage*)fromCVMat:(const cv::Mat&)cvMat
{
    // (1) Construct the correct color space
    CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace;
    if ( cvMat.channels() == 1 ) {
        colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceGray();
    } else {
        colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
    }

    // (2) Create image data reference
    CFDataRef data = CFDataCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault, cvMat.data, (cvMat.elemSize() * cvMat.total()));

    // (3) Create CGImage from cv::Mat container
    CGDataProviderRef provider = CGDataProviderCreateWithCFData(data);
    CGImageRef imageRef = CGImageCreate(cvMat.cols,
                                        cvMat.rows,
                                        8,
                                        8 * cvMat.elemSize(),
                                        cvMat.step[0],
                                        colorSpace,
                                        kCGImageAlphaNone | kCGBitmapByteOrderDefault,
                                        provider,
                                        NULL,
                                        false,
                                        kCGRenderingIntentDefault);

    // (4) Create UIImage from CGImage
    UIImage * finalImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef];

    // (5) Release the references
    CGImageRelease(imageRef);
    CGDataProviderRelease(provider);
    CFRelease(data);
    CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);

    //    UIImage * imgNew = [self cloneWithAlpha:finalImage :.3];
    // (6) Return the UIImage instance
    return finalImage;
}
```

and then converting a UIImage into a cv::Mat then converting it back into UIImage, with the following code

```
    cv::Mat currentCVFrame=[img toCVMat];
    UIImage* testImage = [UIImage fromCVMat:currentCVFrame];
```

If I save the UIImage before converting it, then save it again after converting it back into UIImage, I can notice a difference in the file size (about 20% less for the second one). I understand that there are some quality loss when making the conversion. Anyone can confirm that and tell me if there is something wrong with my conversion functions?

Answer (score 2):

Try using below code

```
   + (UIImage *)UIImageFromCVMat:(cv::Mat)cvMat
{
    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithBytes:cvMat.data length:cvMat.elemSize()*cvMat.total()];
    CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace;

    if (cvMat.elemSize() == 1) {
        colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceGray();
    } else {
        colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
    }

    CGDataProviderRef provider = CGDataProviderCreateWithCFData((__bridge CFDataRef)data);

    // Creating CGImage from cv::Mat
    CGImageRef imageRef = CGImageCreate(cvMat.cols,                                 //width
                                        cvMat.rows,                                 //height
                                        8,                                          //bits per component
                                        8 * cvMat.elemSize(),                       //bits per pixel
                                        cvMat.step[0],                            //bytesPerRow
                                        colorSpace,                                 //colorspace
                                        kCGImageAlphaNoneSkipLast|kCGBitmapByteOrderDefault,// bitmap info
                                        provider,                                   //CGDataProviderRef
                                        NULL,                                       //decode
                                        false,                                      //should interpolate
                                        kCGRenderingIntentDefault                   //intent
                                        );


    // Getting UIImage from CGImage
    UIImage *finalImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef];
    CGImageRelease(imageRef);
    CGDataProviderRelease(provider);
    CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);
    return finalImage;
}

+ (cv::Mat)cvMatFromUIImage:(UIImage *)image
{
    CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGImageGetColorSpace(image.CGImage);
    CGFloat cols,rows;
    if  (image.imageOrientation == UIImageOrientationLeft
         || image.imageOrientation == UIImageOrientationRight) {
        cols = image.size.height;
        rows = image.size.width;
    }
    else{
        cols = image.size.width;
        rows = image.size.height;

    }


    cv::Mat cvMat(rows, cols, CV_8UC4); // 8 bits per component, 4 channels

    CGContextRef contextRef = CGBitmapContextCreate(cvMat.data,                 // Pointer to backing data
                                                    cols,                       // Width of bitmap
                                                    rows,                       // Height of bitmap
                                                    8,                          // Bits per component
                                                    cvMat.step[0],              // Bytes per row
                                                    colorSpace,                 // Colorspace
                                                    kCGImageAlphaNoneSkipLast |
                                                    kCGBitmapByteOrderDefault);

    CGContextDrawImage(contextRef, CGRectMake(0, 0, cols, rows), image.CGImage);
    CGContextRelease(contextRef);


    cv::Mat cvMatTest;
    cv::transpose(cvMat, cvMatTest);

    if  (image.imageOrientation == UIImageOrientationLeft
         || image.imageOrientation == UIImageOrientationRight) {

    }
    else{
        return cvMat;

    }
    cvMat.release();

    cv::flip(cvMatTest, cvMatTest, 1);


    return cvMatTest;
}
```

it works perfectly for me...

Comment: Thanks, 
Just tested, it's providing the same result as my old code: if I save the UIImage before converting it it's size is 1.4MB, if I convert it to cv::Mat and convert it back to UIImage, then save it, it's size is 1.2MB